# How to get a object from JSON to PHP

Tags: php, json, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I need to take a img link (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/51/Minecraft_cover.png) from this api https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles=Minecraft&pilicense=any. How to do it?

I wrote code like this, but I can print :

```
$img_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&format=json&piprop=original&titles=Minecraft&pilicense=any";
$img_url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $img_url);
$img = json_decode(file_get_contents($img_url));
print_r ($img);
```

But how to print only img source?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use the following.

```
echo $img->query->pages->{'27815578'}->original->source;
```

Where `27815578` is the Page ID

Comment: THANKS! I knew that i should do something with that pageid, but i didn't know how to write it in code. Thank you!!

Comment: No worries. Haha. Glad I could help.